How much can the operator norm of a matrix increase upon deleting an entry?
By "deleting an entry," I just mean replacing it with $0$. Here's an example. The matrix $\begin{bmatrix}
1&1\\1&-1
\end{bmatrix}$ has norm $\sqrt 2$, but the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$ has norm $1/2+\sqrt5/2>\sqrt 2$. If $M^{ij}$ is the matrix $M$ except with $M_{ij}=0$, then is there a tight upper bound on ${\Vert M^{ij}\Vert }-{\Vert M\Vert}$ (or something similar)? How does this depend on the value at entry $ij$? You can assume $M$ is real and symmetric.
I've attempted it, but I think there should a better bound.
Let $e_1,\dots, e_n$ be the standard basis. By the triangle inequality, we have $\Vert M^{ij}\Vert\le \Vert{M}\Vert+|{M_{ij}}|$.
If $v$ is a normalized principal eigenvector of $M$, then we have:
\begin{align*}
    \Vert{M^{ij}\Vert}^2&\le \Vert{M^{ij}v}\Vert^2\\
&=\Vert (M-M_{ij}\cdot e_i^\top e_j)v\Vert^2\\
&=(e_i^\top Mv-M_{ij})^2+\sum_{k\not= i}(e_k^\top Mv)^2\\
&=(e_i^\top Mv-M_{ij}v_j)^2 +\sum_{k\not= i}\Vert M\Vert^2\cdot v_j^2\\
&=(e_i^\top Mv-M_{ij}v_j)^2 +\Vert M\Vert^2(1-v_i^2)\\
&=(\Vert M\Vert v_i-M_{ij}v_j)^2+\Vert M\Vert^2(1-v_i^2)\\
&=(\Vert M\Vert v_i-M_{ij}v_j+\sqrt{1-v_i^2})^2\\
&\le (\Vert M\Vert+|M_{ij}|+1)^2,
\end{align*}
which is always worse than the triangle inequality.
So, we have \begin{align*}
     {\Vert M^{ij}\Vert}-{\Vert M\Vert }\le
|M_{ij}|.
\end{align*}
Thanks!

Surely your bounds should be homogeneous,, i.e. $|tM| = |t| |M|$ and $|(tM)^{ij}| = |t| |M^{ij}|$.  So that $1 + \ldots$ can't be right.

Ack that's right. When I redid it, the bound becomes worse than the triangle bound. Thanks for pointing that out!
